# nodejs express jest and supertest Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error

Tags: nodejs, typescript, express, jest

Estoy intentando hacer test con jest+superject a una api realizada con express.
Estoy usando typescript.
Y estoy teniendo 2 problemas, que el test nunca se cierra (debo usar --forceExit para que finalice la consola) y aunque me retorne la petición un 200, me devuelve siempre este mensaje de error:

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback 
>   was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

[image: Los 2 errores]
**Aquí os dejo el código del test**:

```
import app from './../../app';
import supertest from 'supertest';

describe("ctrl.home", () => {
    let request: any = null;
    beforeEach((done) => {
        request = supertest(app.app);
    });

    it("should return 200", async done => {
        const result = await request.get('/');
        console.log(result.status);
        expect(result.status).toBe(200);
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Tienes un test usando Promises y callbacks al mismo tiempo. No se si esa es la causa pero obviamente es algo que no debes hacer en ningún framework de testing. Eliminando el `done` reduce tu test a usar solo Promises ya que el `async` implícitamente devuelve una

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero aun quitando el done, tanto del argumento como su ejecución me genera el mismo error. Incluso en el beforeEach si quito de la definición de argumentos el done me genera un 500 (no levanta bien la api).

Answer (score 0):

¿De casualidad estás usando mongoose? En ese caso, [es un problema conocido](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/520). Es importante cerrar la conexión con mongo una vez terminada la batería de test.

```js
const request = require('supertest');
const { server, app } = require('../index');
const { mongoose } = require('../db');

afterAll(async (done) => {
  await mongoose.disconnect(done);
  server.close();
  done();
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 500)); // Hack para evitar el Timeout
});

/**
 * Integration tests for application
 */
test('list all products', () => request(app).get('/api/products').expect('Content-Type', /json/).expect(200)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    res.data.length = 3000;
  }));
```

En el enlace adjuntado previamente hay más información y otros casos similares.